# How to check when the expected number of inputs stops while using scanf?

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

So a bit of context, i was trying to make a code which reads in the number of jobs and then the jobs themselves goes something like this
4
1
2
3
4

Heres the thing
if i enter the number of jobs as 4
then enter 3 jobs,
then for some reason it reads in the third job again .

is there any way to check and raise an error if this happens? i would compare two values to check if they were the same, but two values can be same.

also
i would be using a file lets say file.txt
file.txt would have the number of jobs and jobs in the format
4
1
2
3
4
and i would use ./mx3 < file.txt
where mx3 is the program compiled using gcc c99

Comment: Check the return value of scanf

Comment: @M.M can't  stress enough on that!

Comment: post a piece of your code and tell what you expect from it and what you get when excuit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can you post some code for better understanding ?

I didn't understand your problem at all but i think that could help you :

> Return Value of scanf

: *copy and past from [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)*

---

These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

---

(I'm new on stack forgive me if i'm clumsy and explain me if possible for my self improvement ^^)